# Determining if a dependent JavaScript file was included

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, custom-attributes

I have a main JavaScript file, we'll call `core.js` that other file are dependent on.

In core.js I am defining an Object that will be required to exist in the dependent files.

**core.js:**

```
(function (){
/* base package */
var core = window.core = function() {
    // Throw an error, the core package cannot be instantiated.
    throw new Error("A package cannot be instantiated");
};
})();
```

**utils.js**

```
/* utils package */
core.utils = function() {
    // Throw an error, the core package cannot be instantiated.
     throw("A package cannot be instantiated");
};

/**
 * Utility: StringUtils
 */
core.utils.StringUtils = new Object();
core.utils.StringUtils.prototype = {

    /**
     * ltrim - Removes preceding whitespaces
     */
    ltrim: function(value) {
        var re = /\s*((\S+\s*)*)/;
        return value.replace(re, "$1");

    },

    /**
     * rtrim - Removes succeeding whitespaces
     */
    rtrim: function(value) {
        var re = /((\s*\S+)*)\s*/;
        return value.replace(re, "$1");

    },

    /**
     * trim - Removes preceding and succeeding whitespaces
     */
    trim: function(value) {
        return core.StringUtils.ltrim(core.StringUtils.rtrim(value));
    }
};
```

Currently, i am adding an id tag to the `<script />` tag

```
<script id="core.js" src="core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and checking it's existence before defining any new items in the `core` Object.

```
(function() {
    if (typeof (core) == 'undefined') {
        var script = document.getElementById("core.js");
        if (script == null)
            throw ("core.js is missing.");
        else
            throw ("Unknown Exception. core is undefined.");
    }
})();
```

Should I be concerned with cross browser compatibility? It is currently working in IE9 and FF5, but I want to make sure it works for all browsers.

Is there an alternative/better way to determine if a file was included or not?

Comment: A 'cheap' alternative is to set a sentinel variable: `var core_is_loaded = true` in the "must be included" file and checking for that var's existence and having an appropriate value.

Comment: Not really an answer, but why make core, core.utils etc functions if you don't want them to be instantiated? Simple object wont do?

Comment: @Chetan the design pattern is loosely based off chapter 3 of 'Practical JavaScript, DOM Scripting and Ajax Projects' by Frank Zammetti. For proper error handling, I wanted to throw an error that allowed anyone using the script to know what they did wrong, instead of the generic "Object doesn't support this action".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work fine, since `<script>` tags are synchronous any Javascript after that tag will have access to `core`. If you want another method of doing the same thing, your could take Marc B's suggestion and set a flag in core.js. The flag could also be part of the core object, like `core.is_loaded = true;` Then you just check `if(core.is_loaded)` in your other files.

Comment: I want to stay away from adding flags inside of core in the event that core threw an error, or didn't become instantiated. If core exists then core.js must have been loaded. However, if core does not exist, there is more than 1 reason than 'core.js is not loaded'